# AngularJS directive's compile function not getting executed if the directive present inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My AngualrJS (1.x) application has a custom directive to do text box validation. The directive needs to be used as an element. the textbox, which needs to be validated, should inside the directive element. The directive has a compile function which has the logic of validation.

The directive is working perfectly fine. but I have a scenario in which I need to show/hide the textbox depending on radio button click. To achieve this, I tried to keep directive inside a `ng-if` but once the directive is inside ng-if, the compile function is not getting triggered. I tried to keep the logic in link function but link function is also not getting triggered. I can not keep the directive in side `ng-show` because during the hidden scenario also the required field validation is still active and don't want to use condition in `ng-required`.

Is there any way I can have my directive executed inside ng-if? I am not sure why it's not getting executed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: May be is that for child scope that created by `ng-if`. to show/hide use `ng-hide/ng-show`.

Comment: instead writing the full paragraph create a fiddlle or plunker it will be easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` and `ng-show` both are used to show/hide a DOM element but a major difference between them is that `ng-if="expression"` removes the element (and of course it's all child) from the DOM if the `expression` evaluates to false.

While `ng-show="expression"` only hide the element based on the `.ng-hide` class (which add `display: none`).

So when you are using `ng-if` and the expression evaluates to false, since `ng-if` has higher priority, other directives won't run or compile. That is why your custom directive is not executing.

Use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.

**Edit:**

I just re-read your question and came to know that you can't you `ng-show` because of required field validation. I got a solution for that as well.

Use `ng-required` instead of `required` and use the same expression which you will use in `ng-show` (currently, in `ng-if`) like this:

```
ng-required="sameExpressionAsInNgShow"
```

This will only mark that field required if your checkbox is checked.

Comment: Oops!! you also don't want to use `ng-required`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shashank. The reason I don't want to use expression in ng-required is there are other validations like min-length. if user choose the option button to show the field and does not enter minimum length and then hide the control then also form is not valid.So, I do not want to handle each validation show/hide. I do not understand why the directive is not getting executed in ng-if == true scenario. I tried to set the priority of the directive to 2000 then also no luck.. :(

Comment: Oh! you mean to say, even if the `ng-if` evaluating to true, that directive is not getting compiled? If yes please provide a plunkr/fiddle or StackOverflow snippet.